# How to customize field's title in "Navigate to section and fields"

Tags: sitecore-client

How to customize the field's title present in the "**Navigate to sections and Fields**" (see image below).

Let's say - I have a field called `Summary` in the template. How to change the text of it based on the Sitecore item location (Multisite) inside CMS.

I have tried to customize the below processor present in the `getContentEditorFields` pipeline. Is this the correct place to do it or there is any other better approach?
`Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields`

[image]

Comment: Don't do it. It's a trap!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to customize it with OOTB pipelines/processors.

Code responsible for this part of Content Editor lives in

**class**: `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm`

**method**: `NavigatorMenu_DropDown`

```c#
protected void NavigatorMenu_DropDown()
{
    // [..]
    foreach (Editor.Section section in (List<Editor.Section>) sections)
    {
        htmlTextWriter.Write("<tr><td><a id=\"Nav_" + section.ControlID + "\" href=\"#\" class=\"scEditorHeaderNavigatorSection\">" + section.DisplayName + "<a></td></tr>");
        foreach (Editor.Field field in (List<Editor.Field>) section.Fields)
        {
        // [..] - other code
        // you need to customize this
        string title = WebUtil.SafeEncode(StringUtil.GetString(field.TemplateField.GetTitle(Context.Language), field.TemplateField.Name));
        htmlTextWriter.Write("<tr><td><a id=\"Nav_" + str1 + "\" href=\"#\" class=\"scEditorHeaderNavigatorField\">" + title + "<a></td></tr>");
        }
    }
    // [..] - other code
}
```

Once you create your own version of `ContentEditorForm` class you will have to let Sitecore know to use it instead of the default one.

To do it you need to overwrite following file:

`Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Default.aspx`

Put your class name with full namespace and DLL here.

```
<sc:CodeBeside runat="server" Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm, Sitecore.Client" />
```